# OpenCV - Create CV_8UC3 (3 channel) Mat from BGRA output

Tags: c++, opencv, format, pixel

I have an `AVCaptureSession` which output the `CMSampleBuffer` with `BGRA` pixels. I'm trying to create `Mat` object only from `BGR`, in the most efficient way, using the data **pointers**.

```
 CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
 void *baseaddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
 CGRect videoRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer), CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer));
 size_t bytesPerRow = (((CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer)
 cv::Mat frame(videoRect.size.height, videoRect.size.width,CV_8UC3  , baseaddress,    bytesPerRow);
```

But it dosen't seems to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data in a `Mat` must be contiguous (with eventually some extra padding at the end of each row).

Your data are like:

```
row 0: B G R A B G R A ... B G R A <padding>
row 1: B G R A B G R A ... B G R A <padding>
...
```

And you **can't** read data like:

```
row 0: B G R - B G R - ... B G R - <padding>
row 1: B G R - B G R - ... B G R - <padding>
...
```

What you can do is wrap your BGRA data in a `CV_8UC4` matrix (i.e. build a matrix header on your data):

```
cv::Mat frameBGRA (height, width, CV_8UC4, buffer);
```

and then **copy** only the bytes you need:

```
cv::Mat frameBGR;
cv::cvtColor(frameBGRA, frameBGR, cv::COLOR_BGRA2BGR);
```

---

Another solution would be to manually copy only the needed data into your BGR matrix (4 is the number of channels in BGRA):

```
// Create the BGR (3 channel) matrix
cv::Mat3b frameBGR(height, width);


for(int r = 0; r < height; ++r) {
    for(int c = 0; c < width; ++c) {

        // Copy only BGR
        frameBGR(r,c)[0] = buffer((r * c * 4) + (c * 4) + 0); // Blue
        frameBGR(r,c)[1] = buffer((r * c * 4) + (c * 4) + 1); // Green
        frameBGR(r,c)[2] = buffer((r * c * 4) + (c * 4) + 2); // Red

        // Don't consider Alpha channel
        // buffer((r * c * 4) + (c * 4) + 3); // Alpha
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Miki! Thank you for replying :) That's what i was thinking to do. Tho i was afraid from this solution, in terms of efficiency. I'm making a live face swap app, and i'm trying to optimize every single line openCV does. Does one of the solution is more efficient than the other?

Comment: Well, second snippet could be improved using raw pointers for `Mat` and few other tricks. I posted like this for the sake of clarity. However, I think that `cvtColor` will use SIMD instructions internally, so it could be more efficient in practice. So I would use first snippet, since it's: a) more readable, b) already optimized by OpenCV developers. In any case, this can't be the bottleneck of a complex algorithm like yours, so I'd just go with `cvtColor`

Comment: Awesome Miki, thanks. Btw, by any chance you might know, if i could eventually create the face swap it self(i mean the image processing, not the calculation), using OpenGL or Metal, i talked with the openCV developer, and he said that openCV seamlessClone(which responsible for the swap) is very expensive

Comment: Yes, `seamlessClone` is very slow... You can do something more lightweight like [this](https://matthewearl.github.io/2015/07/28/switching-eds-with-python/). No idea about OpenCV or Metal, but I wouldn't reinvent the wheel ;D